# python call parent method from child widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to call parent method `printName` from child widget `treeView` 
but Get error like

1. AttributeError: 'QSplitter' object has no attribute 'printName'
2. QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread

why parent is referring to QSplitter ?

Parent of `TreeView` is supposed to be `compositeWidget` since `TreeView`was created in  `compositeWidget`

**CODE:**

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys


class MainExample(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainExample, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.mainWidget = compositeWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.mainWidget.treeView.setPath('D:\DATA')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)


class TreeView(QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)

    @pyqtSlot(QModelIndex)
    def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
        indexItem = self.FileSystemModel.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())
        filePath = self.FileSystemModel.filePath(indexItem)
        self.parent().printName(filePath)
        #

    def setPath(self, path):
        self.FileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.FileSystemModel.setFilter(QDir.Dirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)
        self.FileSystemModel.setRootPath(path)
        self.setModel(self.FileSystemModel)
        index = self.FileSystemModel.index(path)
        self.setRootIndex(index)


class compositeWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(compositeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.treeView = TreeView(self)
        self.frame = QFrame()
        splitterHorizontal = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitterHorizontal.addWidget(self.treeView)
        splitterHorizontal.addWidget(self.frame)
        splitterHorizontal.setSizes([10, 190])
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(splitterHorizontal)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def printName(self):
        print 'fileName'


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainExample()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi, seems to me that `splitterHorizontal` registers itself as parent when `addWidget(self.treeView)` is called and thus the error. What happens if you modify the `TreeView` constructor and add an extra parameter `compWidget` to point to the object you want (store it and use it later)? You would then initialize with `self.treeView = TreeView(self, self)`. Also, what is printed if you do `treeView.parent()` after `addWiget()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The QTreeView is under QSplitter witch is under compositeWidget.
You need to call

```
self.parent().parent().printName(filePath)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to do it with parameter in constructor? so the class is independent of the layout? However, if your method works, one can make it a function and search upwards (calling `parent()`) till he/she finds an instance of compositeWidget! :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be documented (which seems like a little bit of an oversight) but as with other `addWidget()` methods in Qt (like `QLayout.addWidget()`) the `QSplitter.addWidget()` method takes ownership of the child by becoming it's parent.

This is why the `QSplitter` is returned by `Treeview.parent()`. You should use another way to access the parent you want (for instance like explictly storing a reference to the parent you pass into the constructor)

```
class TreeView(QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_treeView_clicked)
        self.composite_widget = parent

    @pyqtSlot(QModelIndex)
    def on_treeView_clicked(self, index):
        indexItem = self.FileSystemModel.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())
        filePath = self.FileSystemModel.filePath(indexItem)
        self.composite_widget.printName(filePath)
        #

    def setPath(self, path):
        self.FileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.FileSystemModel.setFilter(QDir.Dirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)
        self.FileSystemModel.setRootPath(path)
        self.setModel(self.FileSystemModel)
        index = self.FileSystemModel.index(path)
        self.setRootIndex(index)
```